# Use updated properties while an async function is running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to make a visualizer for some common algorithms. I'm using parameters such as "animationSpeed" and "running" for user to take control of animation. I've created an async function for animating the algorithm.

When the animation(animateBubbleSort) is running and user changes the animationSpeed the new values are not  being reflected in the async function. How can I make async function use the new values?

This is my **AlgorithmVisualization** component.

```
const AlgorithmVisualization = () => {
  const [animationSpeed, setAnimationSpeed] = useState(1000);
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(true);
  
  let sortingObj = new SortingAlgorithm(running, animationSpeed);

  const handleBubbleSort = () => {
    setRunning(true);
    sortingObj.animateBubbleSort(array);
  };

  const handleStopButton = () => {
    setRunning(false);
    sortingObj.stopAnimation();
  };

  const handleIncreaseButton = () => {
    const newSpeed = Math.max(100, animationSpeed - 100)
    setAnimationSpeed(newSpeed);
    sortingObj.updateAnimationSpeed(newSpeed);
  };

  const handleDecreaseButton = () => {
    const newSpeed = Math.min(2000, animationSpeed + 100)
    setAnimationSpeed(newSpeed);
    sortingObj.updateAnimationSpeed(newSpeed);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="array-container">
        {array.map((value, idx) => (
          <div
            className="array-bar"
            key={idx}
            style={{ height: `${value}%` }}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleDecreaseButton}>Decrease Animation Speed</button>
      <button onClick={handleStopButton}>Stop</button>
      <button onClick={handleIncreaseButton}>Increase Animation Speed</button>
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={handleBubbleSort}>Bubble Sort</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and this is my **SortingAlgorithm **class.

```
class SortingAlgorithm{
  constructor(running, animationSpeed){
    this.animationSpeed = animationSpeed;
    this.running = running;
  }

  stopAnimation(){
    this.running = false;
  }

  updateAnimationSpeed(newSpeed){
    this.animationSpeed = newSpeed;
  }
  
  async animateBubbleSort(array){
    const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
    const n = array.length;
  
    for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {        
        // Stop the running process
        if(!this.running){
            break;
        }

        const [idx1, idx2] = [j, j+1];
        const bar1Style = arrayBars[idx1].style;
        const bar2Style = arrayBars[idx2].style;
  
        var isSwap = false;         
  
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          isSwap = true;
          const temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
  
        bar1Style.backgroundColor = SECONDELEMENTCOLOR;
        bar2Style.backgroundColor = FIRSTELEMENTCOLOR;
  
        await delay(this.animationSpeed);      
  
        if (isSwap) {
          const tempHeight = bar1Style.height;
          bar1Style.height = bar2Style.height;
          bar2Style.height = tempHeight;
  
          bar1Style.backgroundColor = FIRSTELEMENTCOLOR;
          bar2Style.backgroundColor = SECONDELEMENTCOLOR;
        }
  
        await delay(this.animationSpeed);
        
        bar1Style.backgroundColor = NOCOLOR;
        bar2Style.backgroundColor = NOCOLOR;
      }
      
      // Stop the running process
      if(!this.running){
        break;
      }
  
      const lastBarStyle = arrayBars[n - 1 - i].style;
      lastBarStyle.backgroundColor = SORTEDCOLOR;
    }

    // Stop the running process
    if(!this.running){
      return;
    }
  
    const firstBarStyle = arrayBars[0].style;
    firstBarStyle.backgroundColor = SORTEDCOLOR;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new `SortingAlgorithm` object is created when the `animationSpeed` is increased (and also whenever `AlgorithmVisualization` is re-rendered for any other reason), in this line:

```
let sortingObj = new SortingAlgorithm(running, animationSpeed);
```

So the call of `sortingObj.updateAnimationSpeed`, is executed on the *new* object, while the *old* one is still running, and all the created `sortingObj` instances battle against each other to update the `array-bar`.

You could:

- instantiate `new SortingAlgorithm` outside of the `AlgorithmVisualization` function, or
- create a [custom hook](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks) that guarantees only one instance, e.g. involving [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo), [useCallback](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) or [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect), or
- rewrite `SortingAlgorithm` into a `useSortingAlgorithm` custom hook.

You also should not ever use DOM methods like `document.getElementsByClassName` in React, but that's not the main problem here.

But in the long term you will need to [learn the concept of react](https://react.dev/learn), because it works quite a lot different than what you probably are used to.

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I instantiated it outside the function. Although you are right, this is not a good way to use react.